# How can I execute an external jar in java code?

Tags: java, spring

I have a external Java jar, which renders a textbased format into a graph as png file. To use this functionality in web, I created a spring webservice. In a post method, the service receives the textbased format. How am I able to call the external jar in the spring controller and use the result?
`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar renderer.jar -p")`? How can i pipe the textbased format in the command and where do I have to place the external jar?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You should include renderer.jar into you spring project as dependency. Then you could use classes from that jar.

What is you project management tool? Maven for example allow you to create local artifact (if renderer.jar is not a public library).